# Is it correct to think of vectors as multi-dimensional scalars?

Tags: vectors

I know vectors have two components, while scalars have only one, but vectors and scalars seem like they are much more simmilar than that. A lot of operations you may perform on vectors also work with scalars, such as addition, and multiplication.

For example, if I were to think of a scalar as a one dimensional vector, a lot of vector math would still work, such as the dot product. With this idea, I can think of $2D$ vectors as two dimensional scalars, $3D$ vectors as three dinensional scalars, and so on.

My question is, is this a correct view of vectors, or is my logic skewed?

Comment: Yes, vectors are elements of $\mathbb{F}^n$ (for some field) and scalars are elements of $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{F}^1$.  Any brackets or parentheses people put around the 1-dimensional vectors is largely notational.  Note however that scalars have a few properties that more general vectors don't; for example, the existence of the scalar multiplication operation, as well as (when $\mathbb{F}$ is a field) having a field structure.

Comment: This is a reasonable view, but not entirely correct, because any vector space will be isomorphic to $k^n$ for some $n$ (possibly an infinite cardinal), but is not necessarily equal to $k^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of. The right way to go, I think, is to conceptualize a new concept that reflects the commonalities, and then refine your understanding of "scalar" to distinguish the scalars from other objects that fit the more general concept.

You can reinforce the similarity by constructing the *tensor algebra* over your vector space: this gives the "universal" way to multiply vectors. The dot product, for example, can be seen as a tensor product followed by another map.

The relevant more general concept, incidentally, might simply be "vector". After all, the scalars are one-dimensional vectors!

Comment: So then a scalar would then become a special kind of vector, that is defined by being one dimensional?

Comment: @geeky: Right. Actually, to some extent, the word "scalar" is being used to convey *how* we are *using* numbers in our algebra, rather than what a number 'is'. If you have learned about matrices, think about the difference in how you use the scalar $2$ versus how you use the matrix $[2]$.